# C# Process.Start with credentials fails with Access Denied

Tags: c#, process, credentials

I have a Win Forms application in C# which runs on employees PC's.
Within the application, i call another executable using Process.Start, but i pass a username and password of a user which has administrator privileges on the domain, because employees don't have permissions to run the executable.

The executable is in a folder on C:

The exe starts successfully on Windows XP machines, but fails with "Access Denied" error on Windows 7.
i didn't find a solution. Any idea?

```
try
        {
            var pass = new SecureString();
            pass.AppendChar('b');
            pass.AppendChar('l');
            pass.AppendChar('a');
            pass.AppendChar('b');
            pass.AppendChar('l');
            pass.AppendChar('a');

             var pro = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "myExe.exe",
                UserName = "username",
                Password = pass,
                Domain = "domain",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
               RedirectStandardInput = true
            };
             Process.Start(pro); 

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to call updater.\n" + Help.ErrorMsg(x)); Application.Exit();
        }
```

Comment: "i pass a username and password of a user which has administrator privileges on the domain" - erm, wtf?!? If you are really doing that, you have a security problem and you've designed it wrong. You may have an XY problem...

Comment: do you have code example of your problem?

Comment: @MitchWheat so what do you suggest to run such an executable

Comment: @M.Schena : i added code to the question

Comment: You've just given all of your users (or any attacker that compromises any machine) a domain admin password.    That is a _terible_  idea.

Comment: Why would a regular user need to perform an action that only a domain administrator should do?

Comment: @Will ,what do you suggest?
the executable is actually an update helper for the main application.
should we give all users permissions to run the updater? or create a single user with this permission and use it in the code?

employees users are given limited permission to run specific applications.

Comment: @MitchWheat: i would really appreciate it if you tell me where to learn security best practices in programming. A book.. a reference.. a website...

Comment: Simple, install the application at the *user level*, not machine-wide, so no elevation is needed. With Wix, you would configure the installer to run per user. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/11/18/using-wix-3-0-to-create-a-per-user-msi-that-does-not-prompt-for-elevation-on-windows-vista/ don't know your installer. An example is Chrome, which is installed to C:\Users\lol\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome instead of \program files.  If it must be admin, then use Active Directory to push out the update. https://serverfault.com/questions/13111/how-is-software-deployed-via-active-directory

Answer (score 0):

Hei,

***Win Forms application*** must run with admin privileges in order to start another process with higher privileges.

Your problem is not related to c#. It's a UAC problem.

Given the fact that you are giving them and exe to run something with elevated rights, I assume that you took in consideration that an user can use a decompiler to see the credentials.

- Check a simple solution (and dangerous one) to create a shortcut that lets a standard user to run an app with elevated permissions:
  https://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/
- Or check this for another idea to pass the UAC: https://superuser.com/questions/171917/force-a-program-to-run-without-administrator-privileges-or-uac

Also, if you wanna do it right, I suggest using an MDM solution like Microsoft SCCM (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/system-center-configuration-manager). With something like this you can do:

- In console updates
- application delivery
- software update
- many more

You can control end users PCs and you don't have to give them elevated rights.